# In didSet for an enum property in Swift is it possible to check if the new value is the same as the old one?

Tags: swift, enums

Given the following example:

```
enum ViewState {
    case idle
    case loading
    case caseWithAssociatedValue(String)    
}

class View {
    private var state: ViewState = .idle

    func setState(to state: ViewState) {
        guard state != self.state else { return }
        self.state = state
    }
}
```

I can't compare two properties of type ViewState and I can't use a raw value to compare as one of my cases has an associated value.

What I'm looking for is a way to check if the new value for state a new value or the same as the current value. Is this possible?

Comment: Why the method take state type "State" and the class var state type "ViewState"?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, editing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use willSet and do something like this

```
enum State : Equatable {
  case idle
  case active
  case done(String)
}

class test {
  var x: State {  
    willSet {
      if x != newValue {
        print("\(x) -> \(newValue)")
      }
    }
  }

  init(_ x: State) {
    self.x = x
  }
}

let t = test(State.idle)
t.x = State.active
t.x = State.done("We're done")
```

Output is
  idle -> active
  active -> done("We\'re done")

Comment: I am curious why this was down voted? Is it wrong or inefficient or what?

Comment: Your answer did not answer the question, which was how to compare two enums.

Comment: Ok, got it. I thought the question was about comparing the old vs the new value and not specifically how to do it for an enum.

Comment: No worries, looking back I could have been a bit clearer in my final sentence. I'll make sure to be less ambiguous in future questions.

Comment: My code works with an enum if it implements Equatable so I'll update it.